# Find all subfields of the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Find all subfields of the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $x^4 + 2$.

How can I do this (I assume Eisenstein's criterion applies here)?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})=\Bbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi /8})$

Comment: First of all, I would find the splitting field. Eisenstein can be a decent a very first step in that direction, yes.

Comment: With Eisenstein, you can show that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$